# Problem using the Len function in defining a condition in Excel

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, conditional-statements, counting

I want to give a two-column Excel file as input to my script. But I need a two-column Excel file to have one feature: the second column must have 10 characters. Because the number of rows in the Excel file is large, I can not manually edit every cell in the second column.
So I need to put a control function in Excel to check the second column, so that it counts the number of characters in each cell in the second column and adds zero to the right of it, which is less than ten characters.

Based on my search, I realized that I could use the definition of the condition and the `Len` function, but the output was not what I wanted.

```
 Full ID       Expected Result
  15               0000000015
  159              0000000159
  16               0000000016
  43               0000000043
  4329             0000004329
```

What I had tried :

```
=Right(A2,LEN(A2)+8)
```

but it was wrong.

How can I get my expected results in like the top example?

Comment: Just select the column of numbers and custom format these numbers to `0000000000`

Comment: Yes - if you want to do calculations on the numbers with leading zeroes, better to keep them as  numbers and just change the formatting as suggested :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to use Rept to repeat the correct number of zeroes:

```
=REPT("0",10-LEN(A2))&A2
```

Or simpler to use Text:

```
=TEXT(A2,"0000000000")
```

The nearest to your original formula would be something like

```
=LEFT("0000000000",10-LEN(A2))&A2
```

Or better the formula suggested by @JvdV

```
=RIGHT("0000000000"&A2,10)
```

To be honest I wasn't sure if by simply formatting the data as "0000000000" the zeroes would be preserved if (for example) you wrote the sheet out as a CSV, but I have tested it just to make sure and in fact they are so I think this remains the optimal solution.

*Test Sheet*

[image]

*Resulting CSV*

[image]

Comment: Or even `=RIGHT("0000000000"&A2,10)` =)

Comment: @jvdv that's the simplest and fastest. You should make it an answer

Comment: @PatrickHonorez, we rather keep the answer clean and grouped to this fine answer by Tom =), if anything Tom should feel free to update his answer if he feels it adds value too. I still think OP should just custom format the data.

Comment: Yes, that's really neat - I will add to my answer if you are happy for me to do that.